# No Field for Pre Shared Key in Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, wpa

I am attempting to configure group polocy (Windows 2008 R2) to issues a WPA Pre shared Key on client login.

Through Group Policy I can setup WPA and select PSK (Along with TKIP)
But there's not field to enter my Pre Shared Key!

Any help would be appricaited

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated this in the past... MS simply do not support this option.

Comment: Thanks Aviad, any thoughts on a simple 802.1x setup?